# How to get the count of containers in blob storage account using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

There is a blob storage account, the name of the blob storage account is `azureblob11` it has a container with the name `source`.

The container `source` contains 2 level subfolders.

[image]

The folder structure looks similar:

```
source (container)
  |--a (folder)
     |--ana (sub-folder)
     |--hem (sub-folder)
     |--thg (sub-folder)
     |--oud (sub-folder)
```

I have copied the sub-folders along with their data to the container level and created these 4 subfolders as new containers along with their data.

The folder structure looks like this after copying the sub-folders to container level

```
source (container)
  |--a (folder)
     |--ana (sub-folder)
     |--hem (sub-folder)
     |--thg (sub-folder)
     |--oud (sub-folder)
ana (container)
hem (container)
thg (container)
oud (container)
```

The goal I am trying to achieve is to find the count of containers in the storage account that I have copied from sub-folder level to container level using Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Hello @Azure Cloud Enthusiast, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my list of Subfolder I.e., Output of Get Metadata:

[image]

As a workaround we can count the subfolder instead of count container.As you are making containers from subfolder only.

To get the count of subfolder you should use the **length** function.

Step 1 > On a pipeline Create a Variable FolderCount of String type.

[image]

Step 2 > Select the Set Variable Activity on GetMetaData DataSet.

[image]

Step 3 > Inside SetVariable Activity navigate to Variable and add dynamic content.
[image]

[image]

Step 5 : Now final debug.

[image]

Comment: We can get the Count of the Subfolders but the count of containers. The answer is correct but needs to modify at the end. After the completion of the ForEach activity, we need to add the GetMetadata activity and set Variable activity. In the GetMetadata activity, we need to set the dataset value and the location needs to be left blank so that we can retrieve the list of containers in the storage account and and set the variable as same.